# How can I pass the contact id to another class?

Tags: javascript

I want to call and use `{! contact.Id}` in other class in the `setP` method. What can ı do?

Source code:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="contact">
            <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!contact.Title}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!contact.Is_c}"/>
            <apex:column> 
                <apex:commandLink value="Set As" action="{!setP}" 
                onclick="if(confirm( 'Are you sure?')){ return true ;} else { return false;};">
                </apex:commandLink>
              </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: You tagged this question as "oracle-apex", but it seems this is the salesforce apex product. That has nothing to do with oracle-apex.

Comment: And the html template has definitely nothing to do with javascript

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Just use `<apex:param name="q" value="{!contact.name}"/>` like that